# Possible to export Excel formulas?

Tags: export, output-formatting, excel

I would like to export an .XLS file complete with data and formulas.  Is this possible using `Export`?

For example, here is data and a formula :-

[image]

I can import them, (separately), but cannot export them both.

[image]

I am looking into trying with .COM objects (as per [Formatting in XLS(X) files](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Oct/msg00386.html)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few different syntaxes for exporting formulas, all giving the same results. For example:

```
Export["test1.xlsx", {"Data" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, "Formulas" -> {{{"", "A1*27", ""}, 
{"", "A2/3", "B1*B2"}}}}, "Rules"]

Export["test2.xlsx", {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {{{"", "A1*27", ""}, {"", "A2/3", "B1*B2"}}}}, 
{{"Data","Formulas"}}]

someData = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
someFormulas = {{{"", "A1*27", ""}, {"", "A2/3", "B1*B2"}}};
Export["test3.xlsx", {someData, someFormulas}, {{"Data", "Formulas"}}]
```

For your specific example:

```
Export["test4.xlsx", {{4}, {{{"", "IF(A1<4,0,1)"}}}}, {{"Data","Formulas"}}]
```

...and this is a screen grab of the exported Excel file "test4.xlsx":

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my application uses an add-in Excel formula, e.g. `BDP($E2,F$1)`, which causes an export error: `EXPORT::fmterr : Invalid XLSX format.`

Comment: The add-in formula can be written out to an .xlsx using the .COM object method as mentioned in the link, e.g. `worksheet@Range["B1"]@Formula = "=BDP($E2,F$1)"`.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I see what you mean for that sort of formula. That might be something you need to contact Wolfram about :(